# possible to show maximum query text in trino?

Tags: configuration, trino

We have some queries that are hundreds or thousands of lines long that create a QUERY_TEXT_TOO_LARGE error. Is there a query I can run to show the maximum query text length in Trino/hdfs? I couldn't find it here:

https://trino.io/docs/current/admin/properties-query-management.html

or by doing a search:

https://trino.io/docs/current/search.html?q=maximum#

I don't have direct access to the server this runs on, but I can run queries on it.

Comment: From [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.166.html) - 1MB appears to be the limit? Compiled in/boot parameter/session variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SHOW SESSION](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/show-session.html) command to display all property values, and add a filter to narrow it down to the one you are interested in.